# Operator= Overload with different parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

When I create an object of Example (class), I want to assign it a int value with the equal operator, just to see how operator overloading works.

But I can´t compile it with the following code:

class:

```
Example& Example::operator=(int number)
{
    this->number = number;
    return *this;
}
```

main:

```
Example x1 = 10;
```

Comment: You aren't using the assignment operator in your code. But post a [mcve].

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error: not possible to convert int to Example. I am using the Visual C++ compiler by the way

Comment: Despite what it looks like that is not an assignment, its an initialization, it calls the constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: thanks, I tried Example x1; x1 = 10; and it worked. So does this mean, that if you assign the number directly with the declaration, than it will call the (copy) constructor instead the overloaded assignment operator?

Comment: No, it will look for a constructor that takes an `int` (or whatever type you try to *initialize* it with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what it looks like that is not an assignment, its an initialization. It calls the constructor, not the assignment operator.

Try this:

```
Example x1; // initialize
x1 = 10; // assign
```

In your example it is looking for a *constructor* that takes an `int` as its parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Example x1 = 10;
```

is identical with

```
Example x1(10);
```

or

```
Example x1 = Example(10);
```

It calls the constructor, instead of the assignment operator. Obviously it requires a constructor like:

```
Example(const int& n) : number(n) {}
```